# Oracle DBA_EXTENTS in package

Tags: oracle, plsql

Try to find an object in DBA_EXTENTS by another OWNER.
As I type below it works:

```
SELECT *  FROM SYS.DBA_EXTENTS TP WHERE PARTITION_NAME IS NOT NULL
```

This work.

But I'm trying to save the query in a package

```
 SELECT * FROM DBA_EXTENTS  WHERE SEGMENT_NAME = SEGMENT_NAME_P AND OWNER = TABLE_OWNER_P
```

> ORACLE returns Error(662,14): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: Table or perspective does not exist

I also tried with SYS.DBA_EXTENTS.

Package declaration:

```
create or replace PACKAGE  NEW_TECH_CORE AS

MOD_NAME CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := 'NEW_TECH_CORE';
MOD_VER  CONSTANT VARCHAR2(10) := '1.0.0';


TYPE STORAGE_S_T IS RECORD (
   TABLE_NAME          VARCHAR2(128)
  ,PARTITION_NAME      VARCHAR2(128)
  ,SUBPARTITION_NAME   VARCHAR2(128)
);
TYPE STORAGE_S_T IS TABLE OF STORAGE_S_T;

FUNCTION STORAGE_S (
  DATASTORE_ID VARCHAR2,
  SEGMENT_TYPE VARCHAR2,
  SHOW_EMPTY_SEGMENTS NUMBER := 0,
  VIEW_LEVEL VARCHAR2 := 'PARTITION'
) RETURN STORAGE_S_TAB PIPELINED;


END;
```

Comment: `sys.DBA_EXTENTS`  not `DBA_EXTENTS `  some grants may be

Comment: 'sys.DBA_EXTENTS' don't see

Comment: you need to provide the whole picture. you logon as what user, your package declaration, etc

Comment: I'm logon as sysdba, create user / schema, create package in new user. And want edit package, change user_extents to dba_extents in Function.

Comment: yea, but we don't see how you declare your package. Oh!!! you **CAN NOT have a query in the package**

Comment: if you're logged on as `sys`, are you sure you want to create a package in `sys`? probably should do it in some schema `some_schema.NEW_TECH_CORE` . why mess with a system?

Comment: It's a bit unclear if you can successfully run the standalone query as the new user, who will own the package, or only as SYS. If you can run it as that user, does it have select privileges on `dba_extents` granted directly, or through a role? The would have to be direct for a default definer's-rights package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a query in the executable block in oracle. Trigger, procedure, package, function, anonymous, no matter what. You can't have just a query between `BEGIN` and `END`. You must have either cursor or `INTO`

```sql
begin
    SELECT * FROM .....  -- <-- NOT ALLOWED
end;
```

this will work

```sql
declare
    vA number(10);
begin
    SELECT a INTO  vA FROM .....  -- <-- ALLOWED
end;
```